# Joomla 3 - Print/Send icons not showing

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript, css, upgrade

I recently upgraded a 2.5 Joomla installation to the latest Joomla 3. Everything went pretty well but one error exists that I cannot solve: All the articles show a small gear in the top right corner but clicking this button does not do anything.

The funny thing is when you log in: The button is working as it should and the dropdown menu is shown with options to print/share/edit.

This is the button I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcgCw.png

Does somebody know what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: There will most likely be a error being displayed in your browser console log. Press F12 on the keyboard and go to your console and report back any errors you see. Or maybe you could provide a link to your site perhaps?

Comment: There's possibilities to control these features in global settings, menue-item settings and article settings. Have you checked what is enabled/disabled everywhere?

Comment: I think I checked all the things. But the settings of Joomla are still confusing to me and I don't really know what is important there.

Comment: When I load the site I get these errors: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function | browser-engines.js:9` and `Uncaught ReferenceError: Class is not defined | rokmediaqueries.js:80`. But when I click on the icon there is no error.

Comment: Ahh ok, if this error is occuring, then that normally means there is a missing semi-colon at the end of one of the scripts, or possibly 2 versions of jQuert are being imported. Would you be able to provide a link to your site so we can debug it more easily?

Comment: Both of the scripts are part of the [RocketTheme](http://www.rockettheme.com) but I can't find any errors .. I uploaded the two scripts [here](http://goo.gl/B04KG2)

Comment: That won't be enough as the error might not be coming from these scripts

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a possible permissions issue in the component you are using (Joomla Content or K2). Double check the permissions in the top right of the relevant component first.

If you simply want to hide the cog completely you could add "display:none;" to the relevant CSS in your template.

Comment: The user is trying to figure out why the dropdown is not working, not hide the frontend editing feature

Comment: Your downvote seems a little harsh given that I also provided a potential solution. I included the CSS option in case their concern was mainly about the aesthetics of the problem.

Comment: I would prefer if the button would work. But I don't know what you mean by Joomla Content or K2...